# How to execute the mysql statement in my python code?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I can run the following sql in my my-sql client and return the right result :

```
mysql> select cj.name job_name , cb.build_result build_result, count(*) total , GROUP_CONCAT(cb.id) id_list 
       from ci_build as cb INNER JOIN ci_job as cj 
       ON cb.job_id = cj.id 
       where cb.build_time > date_format('2016-04-16','%Y%m%d')
       and cb.build_time < date_format('2016-05-27','%Y%m%d') 
       GROUP BY cj.name , cb.build_result;
```

[image]

But if I use the following python code , it will return the errors:

**ValueError: unsupported format character 'Y' (0x59) at index 225**

Any one can help what's wrong with my python code ? many thanks~

```
start_time = '2016-04-16'
end_time   = '2016-05-27'

db = MySQLdb.connect(host='xxxx',port=3306,user='xxxx', passwd='xxxx', db='xxxx',charset='utf8')

sql_query  = "select cj.name job_name , cb.build_result build_result, count(*) total , GROUP_CONCAT(cb.id) id_list from ci_build as cb INNER JOIN ci_job as cj ON cb.job_id = cj.id where cb.build_time > date_format(%s,'%Y%m%d') and cb.build_time < date_format(%s,'%Y%m%d') GROUP BY cj.name , cb.build_result; % (start_time , end_time)

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_query)
all_res=cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
db.close()
```

Comment: The query does not have a closing `"`. Can you fix that first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using string interpolation to replace the `%s` in your two `date_format()`s, however, as `%` is a special character wrt to string interpolation, Python thinks that the `%Y` is also a string formatting operation. But it `Y` not a valid format specifier.

You can escape the other `%` characters by doubling up the `%` in your query string:

```
date_format('%s','%%Y%%m%%d')
```

You also need to quote the `%s` since you are sending a string.

However, I would recommend that you use parameterised queries instead as this helps to avoid possible SQL injection vulnerabilities:

```
sql_query  = "select cj.name job_name , cb.build_result build_result, count(*) total , GROUP_CONCAT(cb.id) id_list from ci_build as cb INNER JOIN ci_job as cj ON cb.job_id = cj.id where cb.build_time > date_format(%s,'%%Y%%m%%d') and cb.build_time < date_format(%s,'%%Y%%m%%d') GROUP BY cj.name , cb.build_result"

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_query, (start_time , end_time))
```

This suplies the arguments to the query in a separate tuple which is passed to `cursor.execute()`. The database engine will safely perform the substitution ensuring that quotes and other special characters are properly escaped. Note that you should not quote the placeholder (`%s`) here - the engine will do it for you.

Comment: thanks mhawke for your kindly help and detailed explanation , learned a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to double the percentage signs you do not want to interpolate with argumewnts of the `%`operator and some things in addition ;-)

```
sql_query  = "select cj.name job_name , cb.build_result build_result, count(*) total , GROUP_CONCAT(cb.id) id_list from ci_build as cb INNER JOIN ci_job as cj ON cb.job_id = cj.id where cb.build_time > date_format('%s','%%Y%%m%%d') and cb.build_time < date_format('%s','%%Y%%m%%d') GROUP BY cj.name , cb.build_result;" % ('a', 'b')
```

will work. Sorry for using the string literals `'a', 'b'` to test. You should of course enter your variables.

Also note the added closing double quote after the semicolon to end the string (as @MosesKoledoye noted) and when the database receives the filled in string it would be maybe good to add `'%%s'` to wrap the inserted literal start and end "times" (but not double quotes I think as @sparkandshine) noted, as this will be "More" valid SQL.

As @mhawke notes: **Try to not build a sql query string by injecting stuff from variables**!

One day you control their content and all is well, the next day you refactor the code, and receive the variables "from the outside" and SQL injection is ready to roll - try prepared statements for all complex queries (to offer the DB possibility to optimize already in the PREPARE phase and add layered security automatically by having a better protection in BIND phase rejecting injection attempts at EXECUTE phase time.

Comment: also thanks Dilettant , this problem has bothered me for a long time , I have a better understanding now ， thank you